# How to turn off Auto correct for braces and coded elements in a Visual Studio MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2010, but this applies to VS 2008 as well.

In my MVC views I prefer to write my coded elements as follows:

```
<% if (somecondition) { %>
    <p>something</p>
<% } else { %>
    <p>something else</p>
<% } %>
```

This just looks more readable to me than the following which is what VS auto corrects my code to look like:

```
<% if (somecondition) 
   {  %>
    <p>something</p>
<%}
  else
  {  %>
    <p>something else</p>
  <%} %>
```

I usually stop my work to format the code back into the fashion that I prefer, but am getting tired of this.  I love the auto-correcting in VS, but want this to cease only in my views, and only for what I describe above.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click within your view then:

Pick Formatting and Validation

Expand:  C# -> Formatting -> Newlines

Then uncheck 'Place open brace on new line for control blocks'

Comment: that works for the view, but now I have the opposite problem in my .cs files in that it now auto-corrects my code blocks to put the opening brace on the same line.... if (somecondition) { ....I can live that I guess, as it's more important to me to have the mixed-mode view look clean.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's annoying. Here's how to turn it off:

1. Go to `Tools` -> `Options`
2. In the `Text Editor` option look for t`HTML1 and expand the node.
3. In the `Formatting` option, turn off all `Automatic formatting options`.

Alternatively, in the same dialog, you can configure the formatting for each specific tag. Just click on the `Tag Specific Options...` button.